# Same performance with two threads as with one?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm playing around with multithreading to try and get a better understanding of how to implement it in another project and have put together a small example. The code first generates 10000 strings. There is a function `foo` which loops through each string between two given start and end indexes, checking to see if the character "a" is present (simply for some synthetic load).

When calling `foo` on the main thread and looping through all 10000 strings, the execution time is ~72ms. When using two separate threads `th1` and `th2` and passing the `foo` function pointer along with a start and end index (effectively each thread processes half of the 10000 strings), I was expecting the execution time to be less than ~72ms as it was my understanding that each thread would execute simultaneously, producing an execution time of ~36ms.

However, the execution time is the same as the loop running through all 10000 strings on the main thread. Could someone explain to me why this is the case?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <ratio>
#include <thread> 

std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point startTime;

std::vector<std::string> strings;


bool string_contains(std::string needle, std::string haystack)
{
    if (haystack.find(needle) != std::string::npos)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

std::string random_string(int len)
{
    std::string str = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    std::string newstr;
    int pos;
    while (newstr.size() != len) {
        pos = ((rand() % (str.size() - 1)));
        newstr += str.substr(pos, 1);
    }
    return newstr;
}

const double now()
{
    std::chrono::duration<double> t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - startTime);
    return t.count();
}

void build_strings()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        strings.push_back(random_string(20));
    }
}

void foo(size_t start, size_t end, size_t thread)
{
    size_t stringsWithA = 0;
    for (size_t i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        if (string_contains("a", strings[i]))
        {
            stringsWithA++;
        }
    }
    std::cout << stringsWithA << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    build_strings();

    auto time_a = now();

    foo(0, strings.size(), 0);

    auto time_b = now();

    std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << std::fixed << "main       " << time_b - time_a << "\n";


    time_a = now();
    std::thread th1(foo, 0, strings.size() / 2, 1);
    std::thread th2(foo, strings.size() / 2, strings.size(), 2);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();

    time_b = now();

    std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << std::fixed << "threaded   " << time_b - time_a << "\n";



    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: How many cores does your computer have?

Comment: Is this an optimized build? Can you try with 10 thousand strings and see if this improves.

Comment: `std::cout << thread << "\n";` is not helping you and the algorithm does not do much work in each thread other then the cout.

Comment: Couldn't these calls to `string_contains` also be optimized out potentially? They don't appear to have any side effects.

Comment: Yes that could be totally optimized out with a smart compiler since you do nothing with the result of the calculation.

Comment: system has 4 cores, I was actually using 10k strings but forgot a 0 in the question, removed cout (was using for debugging forgot to remove before pasting code), actually doing something after checking if `string_contains` now. Code has been updated. Performance numbers are still the same between running on the main thread or two separate threads.

Comment: Now you have undefined behavior (concurrent writes to `stringsWithA` which isn't atomic or otherwise protected). And making it atomic would have other issues (false sharing)

Comment: You probably want that `stringsWithA` to be a local variable to the `foo()`  that is printed after the loop finishes.

Comment: code has been updated

Comment: My guess: Threads do nothing on initialization; then thread 1 works when it's joined and thread 2 does nothing; then the other way around. Result? Same perf as a single thread.

Comment: I am testing this now. For me threaded took longer than single threaded.

Comment: Can confirm. Under a release build, the threaded version does seem to be taking longer than the non threaded version.